# Inefficient openMP parallel single nowait

Tags: openmp, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am a beginner in openMP and I would like to simply write three independent blocks in parallel. I used "single no wait" structure. The variables as shown are independent. Type "SpDoubleVec" and functions "transpose" and "prune" are related to Eigen library.  The code works but it is not efficient. 
Any comment to speed up ?

```
SpDoubleVec x1, x2, x3, x4, b1, b2, b3, g1, g2, g3;
double lambda1, lambda2, lambda3;
double t1, t2, t3;


omp_set_num_threads(3);
#pragma omp parallel  
{
    #pragma omp single  nowait
    {
        SpDoubleVec v1;
        v1 = lambda1 * x1 + (1 - lambda1) * x2 - b1;
        t1 = g1.transpose() * v1;
    }

    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
        SpDoubleVec v2;
        v2 = lambda2 * x3 + (1 - lambda2) * zx4 - b2;
        for (SpDoubleVec::InnerIterator it1(v2); it1; ++it1)        
            if (it1.value()< 0) 
                it1.valueRef() = 0;
        v2.prune(0.0);
        t2 = g2.transpose() * v2;
    }

    #pragma omp single  nowait
    {
        SpDoubleVec v3;
        v3 = b3 - lambda3 * x5 - (1 - lambda3) * x6;
        for (SpDoubleVec::InnerIterator it2(v3); it2; ++it2)    
            if (it2.value()< 0) 
                it2.valueRef() = 0;
        v3.prune(0.0);  
        t3 = g3.transpose() * v3;
    }
}

 t = t1 + t2 + t3;
```

Comment: I think you want sections not single.

Comment: Always include specific measurements in a performance related question. "not efficient" is not a good start for a discussion.

Comment: Thanks @Zboson, I tried sections too. It was also the same.

Comment: Yes @Zulan, you are right. I meant there was no significant difference between single thread and parallel.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @Zboson, Is it possible that data is shared in this code and it decreased the efficiency?

Comment: Please describe specifically how you measure performance and include the results (numbers!)! Describe the system you execute it on, your compiler, version, compilation flags. Provide a [mcve]. Edit your post to include that information.